# how to add items in a database for billing systems

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, transactions, knex.js

I'm developing a cloud based billing system and I have two tables in my database namely `bill_history` and `sold_items`. I want to store the Bill number, date, customer name, phone number and total amount and then to return the bill number from `bill_history` and store the array of objects containing item no, item name, price, quantity, amount with the returned bill no in `sold_items`. I'm using the following code:

```
app.post('/billed', (req, res) => {
    const { items, total, date } = req.body;
    console.log(items, total, date);

    db.transaction(trx => {
        db.insert({
            total: total,
            date: date,
          }).into('billhead')
          .transacting(trx)
          .returning('billno')
          .then(num => {
              for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                trx.insert({
                  billno: num,
                  prodname: items[i].name,
                  quantity: items[i].quantity,
                  netprice: items[i].amount
                }).into('billdetails')
              }).then(trx.commit())
            .catch(trx.rollback())
          })
    })
```

Now Entries are found in `bill_history` but not entered in `sold_items`. I can't find the mistake! Help me with this error. The console and terminal shows No Error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to remember when working with knex queries: they are **promises** and they will only execute if:

1. You call **then** on the knex object itself
2. You **return** the knex query inside a promise chain, and call **then** somewhere down the chain

Inside your *for loop*, you have only stated what the knex object should do and **because of syntax errors didn't call then on the knex object itself**.

> .into('billdetails').then(inserts => { /// })

It does work if you **return** trx.insert()...

---

That being said, it wouldn't suit your use case, as when inserting multiple values inside a transaction, you need to make sure all inserts have been succesfull. Using *for* loops the way you did in async fashion is dangerous and won't guarantee all individual inserts have completed without errors and that it's safe to commit the transaction.

One way of achieving this in a safe manner would be modifying this section of your code:

```js
// ...
    .returning('billno')
    .then(num => {
            // We create an array of individual inserts
            // Each element in the array will be a single knex 
            // object/promise that inserts one row into the database 
            const billDetailInserts = items.map(item => trx.insert({
                    billno: num,
                    prodname: item.name,
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                    netprice: item.amount
                ).into('billdetails')
            })

            // we utilize the Promise.all method that will resolve when
            // all individual inserts have completed succesfully
            return Promise.all(billDetailInserts);
        })
    .then(inserts => {
    // ... commits, rollbacks, logging etc
```